# JS Can't center the image following the cursor

Tags: javascript, debugging

I would love the image to be centred to the cursor.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/694nrcLz/36/)

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/694nrcLz/36/`
```

Someone can help?

[inspector screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDd4e.jpg)

Many thanks, Lorenzo.

Answer (score 2):

try follow css code

```
img#image {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99;
    max-width: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

span:hover img#image {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information! This improves the solution but doesn't always place the image at the centre.

For instance, when you scroll up or down the image will be place poorly. 

Do you know why?

Comment: you need to consider scrollTop and srollLeft parent scrolling element

https://jsfiddle.net/p74a5wjr/7/

Comment: Thanks for the help. On my website, the h3 is contained into a series of `DIV`. so this fiddle is actually more accurate. `https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/2wzv6tr1/1/ `
Is it possible to centre the image in this scenario?